# How can I compare two Lists and create another list where the match?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two lists:

```
IEnumerable<bool> a =      True True True False
List<bool> b = True True False False
```

I need to create another list that shows true if the element of list a and list b match. List a and b will always be populated and have the same number of elements. So for example the output would be:

```
List<bool> c = True True False True
```

Is there a simple way I can do this? Would I have to use LINQ? I guess I could do it be iterating through an array but I am hoping there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you can use LINQ through [`IEnumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) to "zip" the two lists together into a third result list.  Zip operates on coordinating elements in both lists to produce a third list.

The second parameter is a function defining what you want to do with each pair of elements.

```
var c = a.Zip(b, (p, q) => p == q).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SequenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
lst1.SequenceEquals(lst2);
```

Also if u need element by element check u can use `Select` clause (if you have lists or arrays not enumerable):

```
lst1.Select((x,index)=>lst2[index] == x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise operators, you can hand code each element to compare or use loop.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<bool> a = new List<bool>() { true, true, true, false };
        List<bool> b = new List<bool>() { true, true, false, false };
        List<bool> answers = new List<bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Count; i++)
        {
            answers.Add(a.ElementAt<bool>(i) & b.ElementAt<bool>(i));

        }

         foreach (bool B in answers)
            Console.WriteLine(B);

         Console.ReadKey();

     }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah but how can I apply bitwise operators to my two lists? Can it be done without looping?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

1) If there is not a lot of data, just loop through and create a new List

2) Implement IEnumerable and create your own view into the two lists (take them as the constructor), and implement the methods such that they use the underlying lists (i.e. for Current : get, do the comparison between the two lists in realtime)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really easy way to go about it without using LINQ, but using good old fashioned for loops :-)

In this method you have to convert your `IEnumerable<bool>` into a `List<bool>`, but that is trivial.

```
        IEnumerable<bool> z = new List<bool> { true, true, true, false };
        var a = new List<bool>(z);
        var b = new List<bool> { true, true, false, false };
        var result = new List<bool>();

        for (int i = 0; i < b.Count ; i++) {
            result.Add(a[i] && b[i]);
         }


        foreach (var r in result)
                Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IComparable and compare two lists and get the result in the ghosts list.